# Meteor catching errors on email.send()

Tags: email, meteor, try-catch

In the [meteor email](http://docs.meteor.com/#email_send) documentation it is written

```
Email.send({
      to: to,
      from: from,
      subject: subject,
      text: text
    });
```

> Send an email. Throws an Error on failure to contact mail server or if
>   mail server returns an error

Should I assume this is done synchronously on the server side and that I should use a try/catch statement in order to know if the mail did sent successfully ? If so then I would have to assume that no catch means no error ?

Comment: Any others solutions about it ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've answered this yourself:

- It is sychronous
- You would use `try`/`catch` in the case the mail server returns an error (if you've set `MAIL_URL`)
- No catch means no error, again provided you've set `MAIL_URL` as the environmental variable.

Comment: Good, I just needed a confirm

Comment: Any others solutions about it ? Thank you